# How to convert numbers to day of the week name?

Tags: php, week-number, weekday

My code for reference:

```
$data1 = date('d-m-Y');
$array = array();
$i = 0;
while($i < 20){
    $datagenerica = substr($data1,stripos($data1,'-'));
    $datagenerica = $i.$datagenerica;
    $data = date('w',strtotime($datagenerica));
    $array[] = $data;
    $i++;
}
$array = array_unique($array);
sort($array);
```

I need the numbers stored within this array to be converted to weekday names, for example: `1 = Sunday`. I would also like to know if this can be done natively in PHP, or will it be necessary to use a library?

Comment: I know I can just make an array with the names of the days of the week, but I want to make a universal code that works with everyone's calendar. I also accept tips on how to do this in another way.

Comment: What do you mean by "everyone's calendar?" Why not just make an array with days of the week and use the values of `$array` as indexes into that array of weekdays?

Comment: could  you give the actual result of the array? and put some details

Comment: if you put the array of weekdays name and get the name according to indexes, it will also work with everyone's calendar as per the date as you wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with "with everyone's" you want to create the array with the names of the days of the week in a certain language. The [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) together with [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) is the right class for this.

```
$lang = 'es';
$IntlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(NULL,NULL,NULL);
$weekdays = [];

//Here you can specify with which day of the week the array should begin.
$date = date_create("last Monday");

for($i=0; $i<7;$i++){
  $weekdays[] = $IntlDateFormatter->formatObject($date,"EEEE",$lang);
  $date->modify("+1 Day"); 
}

//test output
echo '<pre>';
var_export($weekdays);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'lunes',
  1 => 'martes',
  2 => 'miércoles',
  3 => 'jueves',
  4 => 'viernes',
  5 => 'sábado',
  6 => 'domingo',
)
```